# Understanding these Fibonacci functions in Clojure

Tags: clojure

The code I'm trying to understand is made up of two functions:

```
(defn fib-step [[a b]]
  [b (+ a b)])
```

I'm pretty sure I've got this figured out. It uses a macro (defn) to create a named function (fib-step) which takes n number of arguments. It then destructures these arguments into two variables, a and b. It returns a vector comprised of b in the first place, and the addition of a and b together in the second place.

I'm now trying to work through this function:

```
(defn fib-seq []
  (map first (iterate fib-step [0 1])))
```

Again, it uses a macro to create a named function fib-seq. I think I understand the iterate function being seeded with the [0 1] vector but I'm confused around the **map** and **first** functions.

I understand that map needs to take a function along with a sequence, so why have they used "first"?

Why can't I just write

```
(take 5 (iterate fib-step [0 1]))
```

To get the first 5 numbers in the lazy sequence? What's the purpose of the map and first?

Sorry for such a basic question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the REPL:

```
(take 5 (iterate fib-step [0 1]))
;=> ([0 1] [1 1] [1 2] [2 3] [3 5])
```

Is that what you wanted? No, with input of `[f_n f_{n+1}]` the output of `fib-step` is `[f_{n+1} f_{n+2}]`. The `f_{n+1}` term has been repeated. Furthermore, the output is in pairs.

What you really want is the first of each of these pairs.

How do get the first? `first`

How do you do that over the sequence of pairs? `map`

Comment: Ah, I think it just clicked for me. Iterate has to to take the output of itself to know how to increment itself right? And because we need to deal with the previous number in the sequence, we always have to pass pairs around.

Comment: Iterate is just a looping construct that returns the result of every step as part of a lazy-sequence. This is only one variation of a classical pattern that usually includes tail recursion to implement looping purely functionally. The goal of this variation is to let the loop produce part of the result in every step to allow infinite looping in theory and be able to do the necessary computation only on demand.